# Thermodynamics and entropy

Tags: thermodynamics, solid-state-physics, entropy, physical-chemistry

In a thermodynamics process, when heat is exchanged ($\Delta H$), it causes a change of system from state 1 to state 2. As a result, the entropy of a system is changed irreversibly.

Can the change in entropy of a system be changed by exchanging the amount $T \Delta S$?

Comment: I am not sure what your question is, are you asking if adding to a system an amount of heat dQ=TdS then the entropy will be changed? If so the answer is yes

Comment: The premise doesn’t seem to be correct; it’s common  to model $\Delta H$ changes as reversible. And since $T\neq 0$, $T\Delta S\neq 0$ certainly implies $\Delta S\neq 0$ and vice versa.

Comment: Sorry, I mean by the way the amount of delta H is exchange with the system, it also causes the changes in entropy of a system. Therefore, the amout TdS is the amout of heat accounted for the change of entropy ? Why it is exchanged as the infinitesimal amout of heat( reversible process ) ?

Comment: TdS is equal to dQ only if the process is reversible.

Comment: "As a result, the entropy of a system is changed irreversibly." that's true only if the heat transfer is irreversible.

Answer (score 0):

Whether there is an exchange of heat or not in a thermodynamic process depends on the properties of the process. Enthalpy is a function of state, and its difference does not depend on the specific process. So, I would start by saying that some heat exchanged $Q$ causes a change of system from state 1 to state 2. If the process is under constant pressure, we can write
$$
dH = Q
$$
if states 1 and 2 are close enough (see, for instance, the part of the [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Enthalpy#Relationship_to_heat) on enthalpy related to heat exchanges). The fact that $H$ is a function of state allows us to rewrite the previous formula as
$$
dH = Q= C_p dT = T dS\tag{1}
$$
depending on which quantity we want to use as the independent variable.

For finite differences, we have to integrate equations ($1$) to get
$$
\Delta H = \int_{T_1}^{T_2}C_p(T,p) dT = \int_{S_1}^{S_2}T(S,p) dS.\tag{2}
$$
Therefore, in general, we cannot write $\Delta H = T \Delta S$, due to the dependence of $T$ on $S$. To get $\Delta S$, for finite differences, we have to evaluate
$$
\Delta S = \int_1^2 \frac{dH}{T}.
$$
Only in the case of states 1 and 2 close enough can we identify the exchanged heath with $TdS$.